# How to set up Visual Studio 2015 to recognize jquery in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I'm just starting out with typescript (and node for that matter), coming from a C# background.

I'm struggling to get jquery imported into my asp.net mvc project (where I'm using typescript).  What I would like is to see jquery functions autocompleted (or at least not actively complaining, but when I use them with objects, I get the message:

> Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Object'

I also can't access $. syntax.

From another SO answer, I tried the following,

```
>npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

But I got this in return (perhaps I'm not telling npm the correct folder, but I'm not sure how to do that).

```
D:\location\of\my\csproj\file

    npm install --save-dev @types/jquery npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\_dist\package.jso n' D:\_dist `--
    @types/jquery@2.0.40

    npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
    'D:\_dist\package.json' npm WARN _dist No description npm WARN _dist
    No repository field. npm WARN _dist No README data npm WARN _dist No
    license field.
```

And after doing this, I added `import $ from "jquery";` into my code. Not surprisingly, it doesn't find jquery, and I'm not able to properly reference it.

So my question is what do I need to do to get this to work?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining that there is no `package.json` file in the directory. So either you're executing this in the wrong directory (should be in your project root), or `package.json` hasn't yet been created in the project root.

If the latter, go to the project root and execute the following at the command line:

```
npm init
```

Once `init` has been run and the `package.json` file created the JQuery types will be available.

**EDIT:** Revised; advice above is incorrect. NPM should have installed the type file regardless of the errors presented. Next potential issue is that TypeScript is not recognizing the definition file.

What's likely at this point is that the compiler is not recognizing the type files. I don't see any reference to your `tsconfig.json` file. If you have not yet ran it in your project root, please run the below to create a default file:

```
tsc --init
```

TypeScript will automatically import definition files provided by `@types` packages, but only if a `tsconfig.json` file exists.

Comment: This is an asp.net mvc project, so there is no package.json file at the root. Can I add a blank one, or is there some minimum amount of content that needs to be there?

Comment: @Kolichikov I'm actually no longer sure that's the problem. I just tried executing both commands on a folder w/o package.json and it installed fine. Which means the issue is w/ your TS config and/or IDE setup, and not `npm` Can you please confirm whether `project_root/node_modules/@types/jQuery` exists?